# When I use split("."), why does it return an empty array?

Tags: java, arrays

When I use `split(".")` the code returns an empty array.
But when I use `split("\\\\.")` the code returns `[12, 23, 3, 45]`.
Can anyone explain why is it like this?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="12.23.3.45";
        String str1[]=str.split(".");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str1));
    }
}

output:
[]

import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="12.23.3.45";
        String str1[]=str.split("\\.");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str1));
    }
}

output:
[12, 23, 3, 45]
```

Comment: `.` is a reserved regex char. Replacing it with `\\.` escapes it

Comment: From the docs of [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html): "*`.` Any character (may or may not match line terminators)*"

Answer (score 0):

This is a definition of the `String.split()`:

```java
public String[] split(String regex) {
    return split(regex, 0);
}
```

As you can see, the method accepts the **regular expression** (not a plain string). Do use the following instead:

```java
str.split("\\.")
```

Check this out with [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/upyGvj/1)

Comment: The important part here is is the following passage form [`String::split`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)): "*This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.***"